# UrlPattern doesn't matches alphanumeric

Tags: dart

I'am using Route lib and I want to deal url with just alphanumeric like `/Hello123`

I defined this pattern :

```
var pattern = r"/[a-zA-z0-9]+";
```

It's work this Regex :

```
new RegExp(pattern).hasMatch(text);
```

But failing with UrlPattern :

```
new UrlPattern(pattern).matches(text);
```

UrlPattern transforms my pattern in new pattern :

```
^/\[a-zA-z0-9\]\+$
```

What regex can I set for UrlPattern can recognize alphanumerics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-literals in a UrlPattern must be in a group, so that they can be replaced with a value when reversed. Try this:

```
var pattern = r"/(\w+)";
```

Comment: This pattern is not exactly the same because it accepts underscores, but it doesn't matter in my usage. Thanks !